# Is it required to migrate WCF project to .net core API

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core-webapi

The question is regarding - Whether it is required to move WCF project to .Net Core WEB API?

We have a product written in WCF and with good about of business-rules are written into it. Though WCF technology is quite older and is Microsoft putting up the end-of-life/service?

If there is an end of life soon what precaution is to be taken prior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Communication Framework (WCF) may be deprecated in .NET 5/6+, but it doesn’t mean your applications are going to be left out in the cold. Just like Web Forms and other .NET Framework technologies, your WCF applications will continue to work for a long time. In fact, WCF will likely work for the next two decades thanks to .NET Framework being considered part of the windows operating system.

You can also choose to use alternatives to wcf: gRPC, CoreWCF, and ASP.NET Core MVC.
https://visualrecode.com/blog/wcf-alternatives-for-net5/
https://blogs.zeiss.com/digital-innovation/en/topic/wcf-alternatives/